# What is difference between relation with ->profiles() and ->profiles in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

What is difference between relation `with->profiles()` and `->profiles` in Laravel?

Comment: `with->profiles()` or `->profiles()` ? Better share a complete snippet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`->profiles` returns a collection of the related model(s)

`->profiles()` returns an instance of the relationship which is handy if you want to update related models

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
$posts = $user->posts; // model -> collection
$posts = $user->posts()->get(); // model -> relation -> collection
```

Read more here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/dynamic-property-vs-method-in-eloquent-orm

Comment: Thanks i understand now